# Easings CSS gradients being changed with addClass

Tags: jquery, css, animation, easing

In this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ptba8Lzd/

I have done everything correctly so that the properties being changed with `addClass` will do so smoothly (using `transition: all 2.5s ease-out;`).

You can see this working fine with the `height` property. However, when switching from one transient to another, it does so abruptly. Why? How can I switch smootly between these two?

```
linear-gradient(to bottom, #25211e 0%, rgba(37, 33, 30, 0) 100%);

linear-gradient(to bottom, #25211e 0%, rgba(37, 33, 30, 255) 100%);
```

Comment: as a side note, the 255 is wrong, it should be 1

Comment: in your case, since you have transparent color, you only need to do transition on background-color like this: https://jsfiddle.net/8bswkq3c/

Comment: thanks a lot! That's what I originally tried but it didn't work in production. Tried it now and it works, have no idea what was wrong before: thanks!